# Particle Properties

Tags: particles

[image]I am trying this program for the first time and have never used any 3D software before. I am self teaching at this point as well. Please bare with me if I am missing something basic.

I was looking to make an animated intro video and I was able to complete all the motions the way i liked. When I went to go render the video however, the image of a tire bouncing around screen was unable to render into my video. Oddly enough the image as a standalone without being a moving object rendered just fine as I can access it with the dropdown arrow. I have tried since reloading the image in a couple times. The image was originally edited through adobe photoshop. So I did try taking the original unedited photo to see if there was a problem there. No resolve. Looking online I saw that people had made mention of changing the settings in particle properties. The tab itself does not appear at all. I did try converting my image to a mesh as well. Also, I did confirm that the camera symbol is not "x"ed

My image is rigid in that it is a 2D image bouncing across screen right to left. The image in itself is not in motion. The wheel is not say rotating counterclockwise while moving in an opposing direction. The part of "mesh" that I am clipped on. Is that while trying to render my video, it is pulling everything aside from my tire. All animations of my letters moving and lighting and colors carry over perfectly. Online, it said there was a setting inside the tab for particles that is "render" and that in there to click the box "show emitter". Which the particle tab is not there.
I am not looking to add particles into my image. I am simply wanting my image of my 2D tire bouncing across my screen to show up when I render. [animation before render with available settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV1GW.png)[image: mid animation photo where tire is absent]

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are actually doing there. You have a bouncing tire, is it a rigid body simulation? Or something else? And which image as a standalone? The image of the tire? A background image/movie? And why change particle properties? What is done with particles in your scene? Converting the image to a mesh - how did you place it in the scene before it was a mesh?

Comment: Hi Brendan - we all started at one point in our life with Blender - that's not the problem. But....your description is very chaotic and it is neither clear what you did nor what you want to achieve. So you should edit your question, and describe as easy and clear as possible what you have (even better with screenshots) and what you wanna have (even better with screenshots). And since you are a beginner, providing your blend file is also a good idea. And be careful: just ask one question at a time - but you can open as many as you want.

Comment: Hi, Brendan, welcome to BSE. I'm almost sure you will have slipped up on something simple, which is great, because it will be simple to fix. But his post covers so many aspects of the application, it's enough to make our heads spin. Please try eating this elephant one spoonful at a time. Address one element at a time. When you get stuck at a step that you can describe in a self-contained way, come to us with that, making your immediate goals clear. Illustrations usually help, and you can share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ . This post has to be edited before it can be answered.

Comment: Hey everyone, sorry for the delay. My image is rigid in that it is a 2D image bouncing across screen right to left. The image in itself is not in motion. The wheel is not say rotating counterclockwise while moving in an opposing direction. The part of "mesh" that I am clipped on. Is that while trying to render my video, it is pulling everything aside from my tire. All animations of my letters moving and lighting and colors carry over perfectly. Online, it said there was a setting inside the tab for particles that "render" and that in there to click the box "show emitter". Which is not there.

Comment: I am not looking to add particles into my image. I am simply wanting my image of my 2D tire bouncing across my screen to show up when I render.

Comment: It looks as though your image has been imported as an Empty object. What happens if you enable the shipped add-on 'Import Images as Planes', and use that, instead?

Comment: I was able to figure it out. And please let me know if my solution was the only answer moving forward but, I attached my reference image to an object and then make everything scale properly.